# I want to make sure from the logic of my code

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get the number of people who made more than one order to know the retention rate, but there is a problem that if a customer made an order with 4 items there will be 4 values to the order date but with the same date duplicated so i want to consider them one order only so is the following right ?

```r
retention <- orders %>% 
    select(Email, `Created at`) %>%
    group_by(Email) %>%
    summarise(number_of_orders = length(unique(`Created at`))) %>% 
    filter(number_of_orders > 1)
```

this is how the data looks like :

```
Email             `Created at`
aalice@amail.com  2019-10-20 12:08:40 +0200
alice@amail.com   2019-10-20 12:08:40 +0200
alice@amail.com   2019-10-20 12:08:40 +0200
bob@bmail.com     2019-10-20 12:08:25 +0200
caitlyn@cmail.com 2019-10-20 11:26:59 +0200
dave@dmail.com    2019-10-20 11:13:45 +0200
dave@dmail.com    2019-10-20 11:13:45 +0200
```

Comment: `length(unique`  can be `n_distinct` in `dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

I think in principle your code should work. However, if your data contain duplicate items that are generally uninformative, an alternative approach could be to drop these duplicate rows using `dplyr`'s `distinct()` function relatively early (i.e., right after reading the data), as this would also speed up your script and might prevent additional issues with duplicates.

By the way: I hope these are not real email addresses from your database? ;)